# System.IO, where do the files get saved?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am saving a File in `Xamarin` Forms using `System.IO` and i am not able to find it in the File-Explorer of the device, when debugging it on Live Player.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "test.txt");

File.WriteAllText(path, "test12345678");
```

It throws no exception, and i can read the file afterwards using `File.ReadAllText`

I would expect finding this file in the Documents folder in the explorer, but i can not find it there. 
Does `Xamarin` somehow encapsulate this from the device, or is it in some hidden Directory, which i am not able to see?

Comment: `when debugging it on Live Player`...so why don't you add a breakpoint and find out what is the value of path?

Comment: The path which gets displayed is '/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/test.txt' i didnt find it with the search function of the tablet. I then connected it to the PC and did search in the Explorer, where i searched for "*.txt" and "com.xamarin.live". I didnt get any result in both cases.

Comment: Open any file manager app in tablet. In internal storage go to Android/data/ and try to find com.xamarin.live there.